# Logic exception when trying to cache routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-10

I'm trying to cache my routes using `php artisan route:cache` and it returns a logic exception because it thinks the route name is already used, which isn't the case. Here's the exception i get:

> LogicException : Unable to prepare route [registreren] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [auth.register].

Here's my primary `web.php` routing file:

```
Route::name('auth.')->middleware(['basket'])->group(__DIR__ . '/web/auth.php');
Route::name('client.')->middleware(['basket'])->group(__DIR__ . '/web/client.php');
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware(['admin'])->group(__DIR__ . '/web/admin.php');
```

Here's the excerpt of the `auth.php` routing file which throws the exception:

```
Route::controller(AuthRegisterController::class)->name('register')->middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/registreren', 'view');
    Route::post('/registreren', 'action');
});
```

I've searched through the routing files if i didn't accidently used the `auth.register` name twice but i didn't. However when i name the routes in the register group, it works:

```
Route::controller(AuthRegisterController::class)->name('register.')->middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/registreren', 'view')->name('get');
    Route::post('/registreren', 'action')->name('post');
});
```

Now i'm wondering, is this expected behaviour? The routing works perfectly without naming the `get` and `post` routes:

```
<a href="{{ route('auth.register') }}">
<form method="post" action="{{ route('auth.register') }}">
```

If this is expected behaviour, then the exception description is very misleading. I am hoping there's another solution to this problem because we've used the same approach for dozens of routes not to mention the hunderds of route calls in our views. Maybe it's a bug or i am doing something else wrong because it would require a huge refactor to name all the routes and route calls. Any thoughts would be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: You have the name on the route group, which means the name gets passed down to the grouped routes, and you'll have the same name on the POST and GET routes. They really should be named differently

Comment: @aynber Ouch, understood, i was afraid of something like that. So the exception is saying it attached the name from the group to the GET route and then it wants to attach it again to the POST route and it can't because it's already attached. I get it. Perhaps you could put that in an answer so i can accept it and give you a vote up. Well off to refactoring then. Thanks for your comment, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named routes must be unique, even if they use different methods. You have the name on the group, so that name gets passed down to each of the routes in that group. You'll need to name each route separately.

```
Route::controller(AuthRegisterController::class)->middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/registreren', 'view')->name('register.view');
    Route::post('/registreren', 'action')->name('register.submit');
});
```